# Generic service Injection in NestJs

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, typescript-generics

I'm working on a NestJS application that includes a JobService interface and several classes that implement it. Each JobService performs a specific task and is run through a JobServiceRunner.

```
// job-service.interface.ts
export interface JobService {
  setUp(): Promise<void>;
  run(): Promise<void>;
  tearDown(): Promise<void>;
}

// job-service-runner.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JobService } from './job-service.interface';

@Injectable()
export class JobServiceRunner<T extends JobService> {
  constructor(private readonly jobService: T) {}

  async execute(): Promise<void> {
    await this.jobService.setUp();
    await this.jobService.run();
    await this.jobService.tearDown();
  }
}

// hello-world-job-service.ts
@Injectable()
export class HelloWorldJobService implements JobService {

    async setUp(): Promise<void> {
        console.log("configuring HelloWorld service...")
    }

    async run(): Promise<void> {
        console.log("Hello, World!");
    }

    async tearDown(): Promise<void> {
        console.log("cleaning HelloWorld service...")
    }
}
```

Users can trigger jobs by making http requests. Here is an example of what I want to do without injection:

```
// test.controller.ts
@Controller('test')
export class TestController {

    @Post('/trigger/hello-world')
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    triggerHelloWorld(@Request() request: UserRequest): any {
        const helloWorldJobService = new HelloWorldJobService();
        const helloWorldJobServiceRunner = new JobServiceRunner(helloWorldJobService);
        helloWorldJobServiceRunner.execute();
    }

    @Post('/trigger/some-other-job')
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    triggerSomeOtherJob(@Request() request: UserRequest): any {
        const someOtherJobService = new SomeOtherJobService();
        const someOtherJobServiceRunner = new JobServiceRunner(someOtherJobService);
        someOtherJobServiceRunner.execute();
    }
}
```

While experimenting I found the following solution: create a custom decorator to inject the correct JobServiceRunner instances into the controller:

```
// job-service-type.decorator.ts
export const JobServiceType = createParamDecorator(
    (JobServiceClass: new () => JobService, context: ExecutionContext) => {
        return new JobServiceRunner(new JobServiceClass());
    },
);

// test.controller.ts
@Controller('test')
export class TestController {
    @Post('/trigger/hello-world')
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    //@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
    async triggerHelloWorld(
        @JobServiceType(HelloWorldJobService) jobServiceRunner: JobServiceRunner<HelloWorldJobService>,
    ): Promise<any> {
        await jobServiceRunner.execute();
    }

}
```

This works quite well, but I am not sure that I am doing it the NestJs way. I've heard that creating things manually within decorators is generally not recommended and I should rely on dependency injection to handle the instantiation and injection of classes instead. So, the question is: how can I achieve the same behaviour with DI?

Comment: Perhaps a better solution would be using the `Inject` decorator. Take a look at how they do it in the CosmosDB adapter: the [access](https://github.com/nestjs/azure-database/blob/ac17c00b65521d16ca9b540ef4f19d06edc6db89/lib/cosmos-db/cosmos-db.decorators.ts#L104) and the [registration](https://github.com/nestjs/azure-database/blob/ac17c00b65521d16ca9b540ef4f19d06edc6db89/lib/cosmos-db/cosmos-db.providers.ts#L14) part.